# SD Card unmounts automatically

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

Each and every time I restart my phone, a **Samsung Galaxy Duos version 5.0.2**, the SD card unmounts itself.  What could be the problem and what should I do to stop this.  Whenever this happens all the applications do not show up.

Comment: Have you tried another sdcard to see if it exhibits the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably with the phone.The problem doesn't persist whenever I go to the settings and firstly unmounts  SD card and then restarts.It's a solution I discovered and as a precaution I have to take before restarting the Os.Take note also that-After restarting I then heads to the settings and re-mounts back- However,you asked if I have tried another SD card.Well I have two handsets and each has the card and I have verify.Huawei doesn't exhibits what I see with this Samsung Duos.Another thing that tends to overwhelms me recently is that;pictures from my gallery doesn't uploads either through android browser or within individual applications.Thanks for your great concern.